# postgreSQL replicate table by chunks

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

Is there any way to replicate on some intervals but not on any trigger for example new row insertion or update/delete bla bla... 
if there are 500 inserts during 5 minutes then replicate everything between these 5min and execute that each 5min...

Purpose of this is to reduce CPU usage in the production table.

especially logical replication is in question due to we want to replicate only specific tables and not all of them.

Comment: If you use streaming replication, you will have no CPU overhead on the master server (because the information needed for replication is needed anyway)

Comment: even if i use streaming is there a way to replicate in chunks? maybe some third party library can do that if not official replication from postgreSQL?

Comment: Why do you think you need that? Streaming replication simply forwards WAL archives that are generated anyway. The only thing you can do is to define a _delay_ for streaming replication. But it is always triggered by a successful transaction (i.e. `commit`)